# pass input max attribute as integer to jquery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to pass the max attribute as an integer to a jquery variable. Just can't seem to make it work. In the example the variable maxqty should be 6.

Any ideas appreciated.

HTML

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="1" size="3" maxlength="2" max="6" />
```

Jquery

```
var maxqty = 10

jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#qtyplus").click(function(){
     if(jQuery('#qty').val()<maxqty)
     jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val( Number(jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val()) + 1 );
    });
    jQuery("#qtyminus").click(function(){
     if(jQuery('#qty').val()>1)
      jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val( Number(jQuery(":text[name='qty']").val()) - 1 );

    });
  });
```

Comment: you could use `data-attributes`.

Comment: if `maxqty` really is `10a` then numerical comparisons are going to fail. And what is that code supposed to do, because you don't seem to be trying to use the `max` attribute anywhere.

Comment: Where you are passing?

Comment: the a was a typo. it's a plus minus button for the input; the maxqty is the upper limit.

Comment: I don't know what further you want to do with this, but the thing that you want to do here can be easily done without any js using HTML5's numeric only input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `parseInt($('#qty').attr('max'))`

Like `if( jQuery('#qty').val() < ( parseInt(jQuery('#qty').attr('max')) ) )`

What you are trying to retrieve is an attribute on the elemenet, any of which can be retrieved with the `.attr` call.

Oh and just in case, [jQuery .attr docs](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: If you're going to use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) don't forget the radix.

Comment: Good point, I suppose Number would be simpler... had parseInt on the brain this morning :p

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`data-attributes`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store your maximum.

Something like this:

```
<input name="qty" id="qty" type="text" value="1" size="3" maxlength="2" data-max="6" />
```

Js:

```
var input = jQuery('#qty');

jQuery("#qtyplus").click(function(){
 if(input.val()<jQuery('#qty').data('max'))
 input.val( parseInt(input.val()) + 1 );
});

jQuery("#qtyminus").click(function(){
 if(input.val()>1)
  input.val( parseInt(input.val()) - 1 );
});
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6HEGm/6/)